# search certain characters in an if statement

Tags: php

.what i want to do is search for certain Initials inside a retrieved record from a database. for example i have a record like this.. "SGA, MNFA, JGA" how do I code an If statement that will search if SGA is present inside the record. If it is found then proceed, if not, then an else statement will be performed.

sample:

```
if($x == "what is the code needed to be placed here to search if SGA is present?")
{
    .some code..
}
else
{
    .some code..
}
```

.TIA guys! More power!

Comment: strpos,pregmatch [php.net](http://php.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strpos($fieldFromDatabase,'SGA')!==false) {


} else {


}
```

If you need case insenstive you can use `stripos` php>5.0

Comment: +1, since our answers were almost identical; and you were faster. :)

Comment: eheh I was wonder why did you post it again, nvm. :) thanks. Even tho I am under that damn REP DAILY CAP so your +1 will not add reputation to me :( @david